# C++ How to make a variable true if another variable WAS true

Tags: c++

I was wonder how could I make a bool true if another bool was true for example with this program :

```c++
for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
  if (i == 3){
    x = false;
  } else{
    x = true;
  }

  if(x){
    cout << "true";
  }else{
    cout << "false";
  } 
}

output :
true
true
false
true
true
```

how would I make it so that the output is this:

```
output:
true
true
false
false
false
```

sorry if this is hard to understand I'm not the best at explaining

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking. What is the main purpose of this program?

Comment: Whenever you see `if (condition) { x = true; } else { x = false; }`, just write `x = condition`. (Same with `return true`/`return false`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int flag = 0;
for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
  if (i == 3){
    x = false;
    flag = 1;
  } else{
    x = true;
  }

  if(x && flag == 0){
    cout << "true";
  }else{
    cout << "false";
  } 
}
```

If you specifically wish to switch your output upon getting `3`, you can `flag` up the case where there is a change in x. See the code above. This is in accordance to your code pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
x = true;

for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
  if (i == 3){
    x = false;
  }

  if(x){
    cout << "true";
  }else{
    cout << "false";
  } 
}
```